# Variable in library path with JMeter is not working

Tags: jmeter

My JMeter plan config looks like this:

[image]

as you can see from the picture the `mypath` variable has a default value `/somehwere` which may change based on the machine that hosts JMeter.

So I added it as variable in the `${mypath}/bin` below for Library.

However if I run a command like:

`jmeter -n ... -Jmypath=/newpath/elsewhere`

it is not working. Is there any way to put that path as variable?

Comment: Can use property instead of variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself as the solution required is using the parameter `-Juser.classpath=some_path` which avoid the need to create an external parameter for that case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amend the variable using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)  like:

```
${__P(mypath,/somepath)}
```

[image]

This way you will be able to override the value using `-J` command-line argument and if you don't provide the override value it will default to `/somepath`

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)